# How many items can I draw without replacement so that I don't hit any bad items with certain probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a set of $n$ objects, and $k$ of them are bad (but we don't know which ones until we inspect them). Our goal is to locate the $k$ bad items, and to simplify the problem, I thought about blindly discarding some items, since $k$ is typically *much* smaller than $n$ (i.e., say 5% of the items are bad).

To start, if we blindly remove a single item, the probability that it is safe to remove is $\dfrac{n-k}{n}$ (i.e., there are $n-k$ safe-to-remove items, and a total of $n$ items). I think I can work out the probability of the next removal being safe etc., and then taking a product of these I can derive the probability of making a number of consecutive safe removals.

More generally, I'd like to compute "how many removals can I make (say uniformly at random) so that the probability of all of them being safe is at least $p$?" The hypergeometric distribution looks relevant, but I'm not sure if it is exactly what I need. (It has been ages since I took probability, so many of the terms I see on Wikipedia are familiar, but have fallen out of my head).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I have $n+k$ objects of which $n$ are "normal" and $k$ are "defective." If I make $r$ random draws uniformly without replacement, then the probability that none of my $r$ draws will be defective can be calculated as follows:
$$p(r) = \frac{{n \choose r}}{ {n+k \choose r}} = \frac{\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}}{\frac{(n+k)!}{r!(n+k-r)!}} = \frac{n!(n+k-r)!}{(n-r)!(n+k)!}$$
Given $n$ and $k$, you can calculate $p(r)$ for $r=1, 2,\dots, n$ to determine the threshold value of $r$ below which $p(r)$ is at least as large as some desired value $\underline{p}$.